# Define Kotlin interface with all properties to be the same type

Tags: kotlin

In TypeScript I can create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), along the lines of

```js
interface IConfig {
   [s : string]: number
}
```

is this possible in Kotlin?

I wanna be able to do something like

```kotlin
data class ConfigDataClass(val volume : number) : IConfig
```

Then later I can loop through all the data class members of a data class that satisfies `IConfig` and know that they are numbers

Comment: Could you explain what does "[s : string]: number" do? Is this just a function?

Comment: Sure! It's saying IConfig is an object type that's keys are strings and values are numbers.

Comment: If I understand correctly, [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) is the thing you are looking for

Comment: But I can't define that a Map is REQUIRED to have volume key and nothing else

Comment: To confirm: you want a data class with a single property to be accessible also as a map with only that property's name and value?

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 2):

There's a few options that are close to TypeScript's [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

The basic option is just to use a `Map<String, Int>`. The keys will always be strings, and the values will always be integers. This matches your first definition of `IConfig`.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val iConfigMap = mapOf(
        "blah" to 123,
    )

    println(iConfigMap)
    // {blah=123}
}
```

What about if you want a distinct type for `ConfigDataClass`? We can use [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html) to easily make `ConfigDataClass` a map, but without having to re-implement lots of code.

```kotlin
class ConfigDataClass(
    private val map: Map<String, Int>
) : Map<String, Int> by map 
//                   ^ delegate the implementation of Map to map
```

`IConfig` can now be used *exactly* like a `Map<String, Int>`, but because it's a distinct type, we can easily write specific functions for it

```kotlin
data class ConfigDataClass(
    private val map: Map<String, Int>
) : Map<String, Int> by map {

    // add a helper constructor to emulate mapOf(...)
    constructor(vararg pairs : Pair<String, Int>) : this(pairs.toMap())

    // an example function that's only for ConfigDataClass
    fun toStringUppercaseKeys() : ConfigDataClass = 
      ConfigDataClass(map.mapKeys { (key, _) -> key.uppercase() })
}

fun main() {
    val iConfig = ConfigDataClass(
        "blah" to 123,
    )

    // I can call Map.get(...) and .size,
    // even though ConfigDataClassdoesn't implement them
    println(iConfig["blah"]) // 123
    println(iConfig.size)    // 1

    println(iConfig.toStringUppercaseKeys()) // ConfigDataClass(map={BLAH=123})
}
```

Finally, we can also easily add a specific named field - `volume`. Kotlin has a really [a niche feature to allow properties to be delegated to values in a map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map).

```kotlin
data class ConfigDataClass(
    private val map: Map<String, Int>
) : Map<String, Int> by map {

    constructor(vararg pairs : Pair<String, Int>) : this(pairs.toMap())

    val volume: Int by map // finds the value of "volume" in the map
}

fun main() {
    val iConfig = ConfigDataClass(
        "volume" to 11,
    )

    println(iConfig.volume) // 11
}
```

Note that if there's no key `"volume"` in the map, you'll get a nasty exception!

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val iConfig = ConfigDataClass(
        "blah" to 123,
    )

    println(iConfig.volume)
}

// Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Key volume is missing in the map.
```

If you want your data to be mutable, you can instead delegate to a `MutableMap`, and change `val volume` to `var volume`.

Comment: Thanks! The only deal breaker with this approach is the last point you make, which is that I cannot make `volume` a required property :(

Comment: @Karveiani You could add a check in `ConfigDataClass`  - `init { require(map.containsKey("volume")) }` - but it would be nicer if the check happens earlier. Where will the original map come from? Is it JSON?

Comment: it will be JSON from a user and in some parts just hard coded

Comment: @Karveiani Ah so this is an X-Y problem! If you want to decode a JSON string from a data class, and ensure some property is available, then that will be configurable with the JSON library you're using (Kotlinx Serialization, Moshi, Jackson, etc...).